# Java Swing JFontChooser "main not found" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, fonts

I'm a newbie to eclipse. (I've done many java programs through command line)
I'm doing a Java Swing project and wanted to implement a Font dialog box.

**I Found that [JFontChooser](http://jfontchooser.sourceforge.jp/site/jfontchooser/screenshots.html) was a nice implementation and it was open source.** I downloaded the source. But when I import it in eclipse it had problems (like "package name did not match",etc.) I rectified them, by matching with the file structure. [I referred to this forum post](http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/eclipse-sdk-the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-317204.html)

I got rid of all the errors but still when I run, **it gives a error box saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.say.swing** Even after a google search I cant find the solution to the problem.

Can someone give me the solution to rectify this problem? If you can please download the source. :)

Info:I created a new package in eclipse with other names like:
java.say.sting AND say.sting. But it gives me the same error or **Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name say.sting.JFontChooserMessages, locale en_IN**

Comment: Do you have a class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

It needed a java properties file. 
Wonder why people @ SO couldn't find such a simple thing. A friend of mine did it for me. AND I feel short of words to thank him.

The propertiers contents

```
    Version=1.0.5 
# #dialog title 
SelectFont=Select Font 
OK=OK 
Cancel=Cancel 
# # labels 
FontName=Font Name 
FontStyle=Style
FontSize=Size 
Sample=Sample 
# # sample text
SampleString=Jaison 
# # font style 
Plain=Plain Bold=Bold Italic=Italic BoldItalic=Bold Italic
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Typically you would not import the source for a 3rd party library, you would just add the .jar file to your classpath.  That would resolve the package name not matching, I'm guessing.
2. "Selection does not contain main type" means just that--you're trying to launch a class which has no [`main`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) method.  Libraries do not typically include main methods.

Comment: Then what should I do. How to call it?

Comment: According to the `JFontChooser` [javadoc](http://jfontchooser.sourceforge.jp/site/jfontchooser/apidocs/say/swing/JFontChooser.html) it is invoked somewhat like a `JFileChooser`.  They provide an example in the javadoc.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me. It resolved the issue. But I got another error. Please look at the edit.

Comment: 'code'import java.say.swing.JFontChooser;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.EventHandler;

Comment: It looks to me like the font chooser may be expecting not to have its files reorganized, which is reasonable.  Try to go back and add the JAR instead of the source files.

Comment: SO really isn't the best format for hand-holding through set up of a Java project--best would be to find a person who knows Java and Eclipse and ask for help.

Comment: Can you please run the code, because probably you can do it. (No compulsion to do in eclipse). And then post how you got it running. Really working on this for a long time, and I would prefer the code to be in simple java files not jar.